# Football tournament with matrix

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a football tournament in C++, in which the user inputs the name of the teams(8 teams) and then each team has to play with the other one 1 time. Firstly, I don't know how to read the team names, I mean I tried to use .getline or just cin of a char array, but then I need to put the teams into the matrix and after the final game my program should print the table. So there's the first question: how to read the names and basically make the program think they are numbers or does it work with just with names, no need to use int? And then the users inputs the result for every game, but here comes the hard part. After all the results have been introduced, the matrix rotates cyclic and then the result stored in the variables(you will see in code victory/losses) overwrites themselves, so at the end, I cannot print the right table. So that's the second question: How can I make them store to the right 'team' while they rotate? Sorry if I didn't quite explain very well how it works, hope you understand it. Cheers!

````
 // FOOTBALL TOURNAMENT

    int map[2][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cout << "map[" << i << "][" << j << "]= ";
            cin >> map[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "The map looks like this:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cout << map[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

            map[0][0] = 1;
            int temp = 0, temp2 = 0, temp3 = 0, temp4 = 0, temp5 = 0, temp6 = 0;
            int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, round = 0;
            int victory_m00(0), losses_m10(0), victory_m10(0), losses_m00(0), victory_m01(0), losses_m11(0), victory_m11(0), losses_m01(0);
            int victory_m02(0), losses_m12(0), victory_m12(0), losses_m02(0), victory_m03(0), losses_m13(0), victory_m13(0), losses_m03(0);
            do
            {
                // Insert result for every game

                cout << "Enter the result of the first game between " << map[0][0] << " vs. " << map[1][0] << endl;
                cin >> a >> b;
                if (a > b) {
                    victory_m00++;
                    losses_m10++;
                }
                else if (a < b)
                {
                    victory_m10++;
                    losses_m00++;
                }
                cout << "Enter the result of the first game between: " << map[0][1] << " vs. " << map[1][1] << endl;
                cin >> c >> d;
                if (c > d) {
                    victory_m01++;
                    losses_m11++;
                }
                else if (c < d)
                {
                    victory_m11++;
                    losses_m01++;
                }

                cout << "Enter the result of the first game between: " << map[0][2] << " vs. " << map[1][2] << endl;
                cin >> e >> f;
                if (e > f) {
                    victory_m02++;
                    losses_m12++;
                }
                else if (e < f)
                {
                    victory_m12++;
                    losses_m02++;
                }

                cout << "Enter the result of the first game between: " << map[0][3] << " vs. " << map[1][3] << endl;
                cin >> g >> h;
                if (g > h) {
                    victory_m03++;
                    losses_m13++;
                }
                else if (g < h)
                {
                    victory_m13++;
                    losses_m03++;
                }
                round++;


                // Map switching

                temp = map[1][0];
                map[1][0] = map[0][1];
                temp2 = map[1][1];
                map[1][1] = temp;
                temp3 = map[1][2];
                map[1][2] = temp2;
                temp4 = map[1][3];
                map[1][3] = temp3;
                temp5 = map[0][3];
                map[0][3] = temp4;
                temp6 = map[0][2];
                map[0][2] = temp5;
                map[0][1] = temp6;

                // Table calculating and printing  ~ also this has to be outside the loop (but at first i wanted to print the table after every 'round'

                cout << "This is how the table looks like after the " << round << " round: \n";
                cout << map[0][0] << " has: " << victory_m00 << " victory(-ies) and " << losses_m00 << " loss-es!\n";
                cout << map[0][1] << " has: " << victory_m01 << " victory(-ies) and " << losses_m01 << " loss-es!\n";
                cout << map[0][2] << " has: " << victory_m02 << " victory(-ies) and " << losses_m02 << " loss-es!\n";
                cout << map[0][3] << " has: " << victory_m03 << " victory(-ies) and " << losses_m03 << " loss-es!\n";
                cout << map[1][0] << " has: " << victory_m10 << " victory(-ies) and " << losses_m10 << " loss-es!\n";
                cout << map[1][1] << " has: " << victory_m11 << " victory(-ies) and " << losses_m11 << " loss-es!\n";
                cout << map[1][2] << " has: " << victory_m12 << " victory(-ies) and " << losses_m12 << " loss-es!\n";
                cout << map[1][3] << " has: " << victory_m13 << " victory(-ies) and " << losses_m13 << " loss-es!\n";
                cout << endl;
                cout << endl;


            } while (map[0][1] != 2);

            ```
````

Comment: Please provide sample inputs/outputs for what you want this code to do.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then yes, it works with just names, there's no need to use `int` for the teams. Now why your code didn't work with team names is hard to say since I don't think you've posted that code. Second question, no idea without looking further, but really when you have a programming problem like your first question you should solve that before moving on and making more problems. Programming is hard enough without building problems on top of problems. So get the team names sorted first.

Comment: @john it's not necessary to use names, but as you said, it's probably that at some point I will need to know how to do it so that's why I asked. The main problem is my incapability to think about a solution for the 'actual' problem.  Basically how to store each 'team'  victories/losses.. without overwriting when position change.

Comment: @cigien basically i put 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 but imagine they are in 2 rows 1 2 3 4 then below is 5 6 7 8. then 1 plays  vs 5 ;  2 vs 6 ; 3 vs 7; 4 vs 8; then 1 stays put and the rest rotate left. = 1 3 4 8 second row: 2 5 6 7 and so on.. but for first iteration everything goes smooth, but after that the victories/losses variables overwrite themselves because on their position comes another 'team'.

Comment: Check out `std::rotate`. This will make that aspect of it easier.

Comment: @VictorBînzar The answer is to create a `struct` which stores a team name, and it's wins and losses. This way all three pieces of information are grouped together and move together when you swap teams around. Data structuring is a big topic, your C++ reference should give you the details on how you create a `struct`.

Comment: @john thank you very much!

Comment: @cigien I've created a bit trivial algorithm for the rotation of the matrix, but it works, I'll definitely check std::rotate